# Parse XML from Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xml

I have this url i need to get form it the XML and parse it.

`var url = 'http://www.omnyads.com/xml.php?query=education&username=user2&ip=24.102.160.176&limit=3&ua=Mozilla&ref= http://www.omnyads.com/filter.php'`;

```
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
                    url: url,
                    success: function(data) {

                    },
                    error: function(data) {

                    },
                });
```

The Ajax returns me this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<general>
 ... ... .. 
</general>
```

And i get this syntax error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < which is comes from "`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>`" and i cant parse my XML.

Other thing.. if i dont use dataType: jsonp i get this error message:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.omnyads.com/xml.php?query=institutions&username=user2&ip=24.102.160.176&limit=3&ua=Mozilla&ref=%20http://www.omnyads.com/filter.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'examplesite.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're expecting to receive an XML response from the server and yet you're specifying that the dataType is jsonp.  So, obviously, it won't be able to parse the response if it's expecting JSONP.  The dataType needs to be 'xml'.

As to your other problem, which you managed to 'fix' by hacking the code, `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'examplesite.com' is therefore not allowed access.` means that you are not allowed to access that API from another domain.  Pretty simple, right?  That's what it says and that's what it means.

JSONP was designed as a way to get around this security feature, but it only works for API's that are designed to return JSONP data.  You can't simply turn it on willy nilly whenever you feel like.

Here's more info on the: [Same Origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

If you had any control over that external API (and I'm betting that you don't), you could ask them to add an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header which will grant permission to your domain/IP to access the API from another domain.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer really really thanks. Wish you everything good dude.